# Getting error INSTEAD OF triggers do not support direct recursion?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a requirement to write a delete trigger,before deleting vendor it will check for existence on other database table ,if relation not found on other database table then send email to admin and set delete flag=1 and not delete record then next time when delete command is issue for same vendor it's check flag and delete that record.

```
create TRIGGER [dbo].[trgInsteadOfDelete] ON [dbo].[AP_Vendor] 
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    declare @apdivisionno varchar(2);
    declare @vendorno varchar(7);
    declare @vendorname varchar(30);
    declare @addressline1 varchar(30);
    declare @addressline2 varchar(30);
    declare @addressline3 varchar(30);
    declare @city varchar(20);
    declare @state varchar(2);
    declare @zipcode varchar(10);
    declare @countrycode varchar(3);

    declare @primarycontact varchar(10);
    declare @telephoneno varchar(17);
    declare @telephoneext varchar(5);
    declare @faxno varchar(17);
    declare @emailaddress varchar(250);
    declare @urladdress varchar(50);
    declare @termscode varchar(2);
    declare @reference varchar(15);
    declare @temporyvendor varchar(1);
    declare @creditcardvendor varchar(1);

    declare @holdpayment varchar(1);
    declare @electronicpayment varchar(1);
    declare @standardentryclass varchar(3);
    declare @exemptionnoOnFile varchar(1);
    declare @taxschedule varchar(9);
    declare @taxclass varchar(2);
    declare @accountkey varchar(9);
    declare @SeparateCheck varchar(1);
    declare @Comment varchar(30);
    declare @Sort varchar(10);

    declare @batchfax varchar(1);
    declare @UsePOReceiptOfInvForVendor varchar(1);
    declare @PrimaryPurchaseAddressCode varchar(4);
    declare @VendorType varchar(1);
    declare @Form1099 varchar(1);
    declare @TaxpayerIDSocialSecurityNo varchar(9);
    declare @Box1099 varchar(3);
    declare @MiscBox9 varchar(1);
    declare @LastPurchaseDate datetime;
    declare @LastPaymentDate datetime;

    declare @LastCheckNo varchar(10);
    declare @LastCheckAmt decimal(14, 2);
    declare @RetentionRate decimal(6, 2);
    declare @AverageDaysToPay decimal(3, 0);
    declare @AverageDaysOverDue decimal(3, 0);
    declare @balancedue decimal(15, 2);
    declare @NumberOfInvToUseInCalc decimal(7, 2);
    declare @datecreated datetime;
    declare @timecreated varchar(8);
    declare @UserCreatedKey varchar(10);

    declare @dateupdated datetime;
    declare @timeupdated varchar(8);
    declare @UserUpdatedKey varchar(10);
    declare @UDF_LONG_NAME varchar(60);

    declare @audit_Event varchar(10);
    declare @audit_log varchar(100);
    declare @dbname varchar(50);

    declare @Deletedbname varchar(50);

    declare @rowcount int;
    declare @TableName varchar(50);
    declare @TableFieldName varchar(50);

    declare @dbcounter int;
    declare @tablecounter int;
    declare @cnt INT ;
    DECLARE @selectVendorno varchar(75)

    select @apdivisionno =i.APDivisionNo from deleted i;    
    select @vendorno=i.VendorNo from deleted i; 
    select @vendorname=i.VendorName from deleted i;
    select @addressline1 =i.AddressLine1 from deleted i;    
    select @addressline2=i.AddressLine2 from deleted i; 
    select @addressline3=i.AddressLine3 from deleted i; 
    select @city =i.City from deleted i;    
    select @state=i.state from deleted i;   
    select @zipcode=i.zipcode from deleted i;   
    select @countrycode =i.countrycode from deleted i;  
    select @primarycontact=i.PrimaryContact from deleted i; 
    select @telephoneno=i.TelephoneNo from deleted i;   
    select @telephoneext =i.telephoneext from deleted i;    
    select @faxno=i.faxno from deleted i;   
    select @emailaddress=i.emailaddress from deleted i; 
    select @urladdress =i.urladdress from deleted i;    
    select @termscode=i.termscode from deleted i;   
    select @temporyvendor=i.TemporaryVendor from deleted i; 
    select @creditcardvendor =i.CreditCardVendor from deleted i;    
    select @holdpayment=i.holdpayment from deleted i;   
    select @electronicpayment=i.ElectronicPayment from deleted i;   
    select @standardentryclass=i.StandardEntryClass from deleted i; 
    select @exemptionnoOnFile=i.ExemptionNoOnFile from deleted i;   
    select @taxschedule=i.taxschedule from deleted i;   
    select @taxclass=i.taxclass from deleted i; 
    select @accountkey=i.accountkey from deleted i; 
    select @SeparateCheck=i.SeparateCheck from deleted i;   
    select @Comment=i.Comment from deleted i;   
    select @Sort=i.Sort from deleted i; 
    select @batchfax=i.batchfax from deleted i; 
    select @UsePOReceiptOfInvForVendor=i.UsePOReceiptOfInvForVendor from deleted i; 
    select @PrimaryPurchaseAddressCode=i.PrimaryPurchaseAddressCode from deleted i; 
    select @VendorType=i.VendorType from deleted i; 
    select @Form1099=i.Form1099 from deleted i;
    select @TaxpayerIDSocialSecurityNo=i.TaxpayerIDSocialSecurityNo from deleted i; 
    select @Box1099=i.Box1099 from deleted i;   
    select @MiscBox9=i.MiscBox9 from deleted i;
    select @LastPurchaseDate=i.LastPurchaseDate from deleted i; 
    select @LastPaymentDate=i.LastPaymentDate from deleted i;   
    select @LastCheckNo=i.LastCheckNo from deleted i;
    select @LastCheckAmt=i.LastCheckAmt from deleted i;
    select @RetentionRate=i.RetentionRate from deleted i;
    select @AverageDaysToPay=i.AverageDaysToPay from deleted i;
    select @AverageDaysOverDue=i.AverageDaysOverDue from deleted i;
    select @balancedue=i.balancedue from deleted i;
    select @NumberOfInvToUseInCalc=i.NumberOfInvToUseInCalc from deleted i;
    select @datecreated=i.datecreated from deleted i;
    select @timecreated=i.timecreated from deleted i;
    select @UserCreatedKey=i.UserCreatedKey from deleted i;
    select @dateupdated=i.dateupdated from deleted i;
    select @timeupdated=i.timeupdated from deleted i;
    select @UserUpdatedKey=i.UserUpdatedKey from deleted i;
    select @UDF_LONG_NAME=i.UDF_LONG_NAME from deleted i;
    select @Deletedbname= DB_NAME();

    set  @dbcounter =0;
    set  @tablecounter =0;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @deleteSql NVARCHAR(MAX) 

    select @rowcount=count(*) from [Mas_Master].[dbo].[Master_Vendor] where vendorno=@vendorno and deleteflag=1;



    BEGIN
        if(@rowcount<=0) 
        begin

                DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
                SELECT [dbname] FROM [Mas_Master].[dbo].[lookup_dbName]

                OPEN db_cursor   
                FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname 

                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
                BEGIN   

                           DECLARE Table_cursor CURSOR FOR  
                           SELECT [TableName],[TableFieldName] FROM [Mas_Master].[dbo].[lookupTableName]
                           OPEN Table_cursor   
                           FETCH NEXT FROM Table_cursor INTO @TableName,@TableFieldName 

                           WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
                           BEGIN   


                                if(CONCAT(@dbname, '_', @TableName)<>CONCAT(@Deletedbname, '_', 'AP_VENDOR'))  /*Not Check For Same Database */
                                 Begin

                                    set @sql='Select  @cnt=count(*) from ' +@dbname+'.dbo.'+@TableName +' where '+ @TableFieldName +'= ''' + @vendorno + '''';
                                    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N' @cnt int out', @cnt OUTPUT

                                    INSERT INTO Mas_master.dbo.testDelete
                                            VALUES
                                           (
                                           @dbname
                                           ,@TableName
                                           ,@vendorno,@sql,@cnt
                                           )

                                        if(@cnt>0)
                                        Begin
                                            SET @tablecounter = @tablecounter + 1;
                                            break;  
                                        end
                                 End



                                FETCH NEXT FROM Table_cursor INTO @TableName,@TableFieldName 
                           End
                           CLOSE Table_cursor;
                           DEALLOCATE Table_cursor;
                 SET @dbcounter = @dbcounter + 1;
                 FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname   
                END 
             CLOSE db_cursor;
            DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
                /* if no match vendor found on other database then mark master table vendor delete*/
                if(@tablecounter=0)
                begin
                       UPDATE [Mas_Master].[dbo].[Master_Vendor]
                         SET [DeleteFlag] = 1
                        where vendorno=@vendorno
                End

        end
        else /* if delete Flag = 1 then delete vendor from current database table and master vendor table */
        Begin
              set @deleteSql= 'DELETE FROM '+@Deletedbname+'.dbo.AP_Vendor WHERE vendorno=@vendorno';
              EXECUTE sp_executesql @deleteSql, N'@vendorno nvarchar(75)', @vendorno = @vendorno
              DELETE FROM Mas_Master.dbo.Master_Vendor WHERE vendorno=@vendorno
        End
    End
```

if INSTEAD OF triggers used i got error message  INSTEAD OF triggers do not support direct recursion.

If I used After Delete Trigger the i got error message

```
**Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.**


create TRIGGER [dbo].[trgInsteadOfDelete] ON [dbo].[AP_Vendor] 
after DELETE
AS
    declare @apdivisionno varchar(2);
    declare @vendorno varchar(7);
    declare @vendorname varchar(30);
    declare @addressline1 varchar(30);
    declare @addressline2 varchar(30);
    declare @addressline3 varchar(30);
    declare @city varchar(20);
    declare @state varchar(2);
    declare @zipcode varchar(10);
    declare @countrycode varchar(3);

    declare @primarycontact varchar(10);
    declare @telephoneno varchar(17);
    declare @telephoneext varchar(5);
    declare @faxno varchar(17);
    declare @emailaddress varchar(250);
    declare @urladdress varchar(50);
    declare @termscode varchar(2);
    declare @reference varchar(15);
    declare @temporyvendor varchar(1);
    declare @creditcardvendor varchar(1);

    declare @holdpayment varchar(1);
    declare @electronicpayment varchar(1);
    declare @standardentryclass varchar(3);
    declare @exemptionnoOnFile varchar(1);
    declare @taxschedule varchar(9);
    declare @taxclass varchar(2);
    declare @accountkey varchar(9);
    declare @SeparateCheck varchar(1);
    declare @Comment varchar(30);
    declare @Sort varchar(10);

    declare @batchfax varchar(1);
    declare @UsePOReceiptOfInvForVendor varchar(1);
    declare @PrimaryPurchaseAddressCode varchar(4);
    declare @VendorType varchar(1);
    declare @Form1099 varchar(1);
    declare @TaxpayerIDSocialSecurityNo varchar(9);
    declare @Box1099 varchar(3);
    declare @MiscBox9 varchar(1);
    declare @LastPurchaseDate datetime;
    declare @LastPaymentDate datetime;

    declare @LastCheckNo varchar(10);
    declare @LastCheckAmt decimal(14, 2);
    declare @RetentionRate decimal(6, 2);
    declare @AverageDaysToPay decimal(3, 0);
    declare @AverageDaysOverDue decimal(3, 0);
    declare @balancedue decimal(15, 2);
    declare @NumberOfInvToUseInCalc decimal(7, 2);
    declare @datecreated datetime;
    declare @timecreated varchar(8);
    declare @UserCreatedKey varchar(10);

    declare @dateupdated datetime;
    declare @timeupdated varchar(8);
    declare @UserUpdatedKey varchar(10);
    declare @UDF_LONG_NAME varchar(60);

    declare @audit_Event varchar(10);
    declare @audit_log varchar(100);
    declare @dbname varchar(50);

    declare @Deletedbname varchar(50);

    declare @rowcount int;
    declare @TableName varchar(50);
    declare @TableFieldName varchar(50);

    declare @dbcounter int;
    declare @tablecounter int;
    declare @cnt INT ;
    DECLARE @selectVendorno varchar(75)

    select @apdivisionno =i.APDivisionNo from deleted i;    
    select @vendorno=i.VendorNo from deleted i; 
    select @vendorname=i.VendorName from deleted i;
    select @addressline1 =i.AddressLine1 from deleted i;    
    select @addressline2=i.AddressLine2 from deleted i; 
    select @addressline3=i.AddressLine3 from deleted i; 
    select @city =i.City from deleted i;    
    select @state=i.state from deleted i;   
    select @zipcode=i.zipcode from deleted i;   
    select @countrycode =i.countrycode from deleted i;  
    select @primarycontact=i.PrimaryContact from deleted i; 
    select @telephoneno=i.TelephoneNo from deleted i;   
    select @telephoneext =i.telephoneext from deleted i;    
    select @faxno=i.faxno from deleted i;   
    select @emailaddress=i.emailaddress from deleted i; 
    select @urladdress =i.urladdress from deleted i;    
    select @termscode=i.termscode from deleted i;   
    select @temporyvendor=i.TemporaryVendor from deleted i; 
    select @creditcardvendor =i.CreditCardVendor from deleted i;    
    select @holdpayment=i.holdpayment from deleted i;   
    select @electronicpayment=i.ElectronicPayment from deleted i;   
    select @standardentryclass=i.StandardEntryClass from deleted i; 
    select @exemptionnoOnFile=i.ExemptionNoOnFile from deleted i;   
    select @taxschedule=i.taxschedule from deleted i;   
    select @taxclass=i.taxclass from deleted i; 
    select @accountkey=i.accountkey from deleted i; 
    select @SeparateCheck=i.SeparateCheck from deleted i;   
    select @Comment=i.Comment from deleted i;   
    select @Sort=i.Sort from deleted i; 
    select @batchfax=i.batchfax from deleted i; 
    select @UsePOReceiptOfInvForVendor=i.UsePOReceiptOfInvForVendor from deleted i; 
    select @PrimaryPurchaseAddressCode=i.PrimaryPurchaseAddressCode from deleted i; 
    select @VendorType=i.VendorType from deleted i; 
    select @Form1099=i.Form1099 from deleted i;
    select @TaxpayerIDSocialSecurityNo=i.TaxpayerIDSocialSecurityNo from deleted i; 
    select @Box1099=i.Box1099 from deleted i;   
    select @MiscBox9=i.MiscBox9 from deleted i;
    select @LastPurchaseDate=i.LastPurchaseDate from deleted i; 
    select @LastPaymentDate=i.LastPaymentDate from deleted i;   
    select @LastCheckNo=i.LastCheckNo from deleted i;
    select @LastCheckAmt=i.LastCheckAmt from deleted i;
    select @RetentionRate=i.RetentionRate from deleted i;
    select @AverageDaysToPay=i.AverageDaysToPay from deleted i;
    select @AverageDaysOverDue=i.AverageDaysOverDue from deleted i;
    select @balancedue=i.balancedue from deleted i;
    select @NumberOfInvToUseInCalc=i.NumberOfInvToUseInCalc from deleted i;
    select @datecreated=i.datecreated from deleted i;
    select @timecreated=i.timecreated from deleted i;
    select @UserCreatedKey=i.UserCreatedKey from deleted i;
    select @dateupdated=i.dateupdated from deleted i;
    select @timeupdated=i.timeupdated from deleted i;
    select @UserUpdatedKey=i.UserUpdatedKey from deleted i;
    select @UDF_LONG_NAME=i.UDF_LONG_NAME from deleted i;
    select @Deletedbname= DB_NAME();

    set  @dbcounter =0;
    set  @tablecounter =0;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @deleteSql NVARCHAR(MAX) 

    select @rowcount=count(*) from [Mas_Master].[dbo].[Master_Vendor] where vendorno=@vendorno and deleteflag=1;



    BEGIN
        if(@rowcount<=0) 
        begin
                Rollback;
                DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
                SELECT [dbname] FROM [Mas_Master].[dbo].[lookup_dbName]

                OPEN db_cursor   
                FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname 

                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
                BEGIN   

                           DECLARE Table_cursor CURSOR FOR  
                           SELECT [TableName],[TableFieldName] FROM [Mas_Master].[dbo].[lookupTableName]
                           OPEN Table_cursor   
                           FETCH NEXT FROM Table_cursor INTO @TableName,@TableFieldName 

                           WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
                           BEGIN   


                                if(CONCAT(@dbname, '_', @TableName)<>CONCAT(@Deletedbname, '_', 'AP_VENDOR'))  /*Not Check For Same Database */
                                 Begin

                                    set @sql='Select  @cnt=count(*) from ' +@dbname+'.dbo.'+@TableName +' where '+ @TableFieldName +'= ''' + @vendorno + '''';
                                    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N' @cnt int out', @cnt OUTPUT

                                    INSERT INTO Mas_master.dbo.testDelete
                                            VALUES
                                           (
                                           @dbname
                                           ,@TableName
                                           ,@vendorno,@sql,@cnt
                                           )

                                        if(@cnt>0)
                                        Begin
                                            SET @tablecounter = @tablecounter + 1;
                                            break;  
                                        end
                                 End



                                FETCH NEXT FROM Table_cursor INTO @TableName,@TableFieldName 
                           End
                           CLOSE Table_cursor;
                           DEALLOCATE Table_cursor;
                 SET @dbcounter = @dbcounter + 1;
                 FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname   
                END 
             CLOSE db_cursor;
            DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
                /* if no match vendor found on other database then mark master table vendor delete*/
                if(@tablecounter=0)
                begin
                       UPDATE [Mas_Master].[dbo].[Master_Vendor]
                         SET [DeleteFlag] = 1
                        where vendorno=@vendorno
                End

        end
        else /* if delete Flag = 1 then delete vendor from current database table and master vendor table */
        Begin
              set @deleteSql= 'DELETE FROM '+@Deletedbname+'.dbo.AP_Vendor WHERE vendorno=@vendorno';
              EXECUTE sp_executesql @deleteSql, N'@vendorno nvarchar(75)', @vendorno = @vendorno
              DELETE FROM Mas_Master.dbo.Master_Vendor WHERE vendorno=@vendorno
        End
    End
```

Please help me?

Comment: This is horrible design... plus it looks from casual observation that this will not work if someone tries to delete more than one vendor at once.

Comment: `deleted` and `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. Your triggers are broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to delete from the same table (AP_Vendor) that the trigger is based on, which will cause the same trigger to fire endlessly (or recursively). Perhaps creating AN after trigger on Maser_Vendor that deletes from AP_Vendor will work.

Comment: If i used after trigger i got error Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted

Comment: You must create the AFTER trigger on Master_Vendor and us it to delete the associated AP_Vendor record. Since you have already applied the validation logic in the AP_Vendor trigger, you merely have to delete the associated Master_Vendor record.

Comment: For First Time i never want to delete records. when second time i delete same vendors then it check delete vendor flag,if 1 then delete other wise rollback.I have added after trigger,for first time it's rollback deleted vendor record and applied validation logic and set flag for delete, on second time it go for delete.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger contains a DELETE on the same table at the end. Normally, an operation within an INSTEAD OF trigger will not fire the same trigger again but since you are doing this with dynamic SQL this creates another execution context and i guess this means the trigger will fire again.

You can check the options for nested triggers and recursive triggers in your DB:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'nested triggers';
EXEC sp_dboption 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME', 'recursive triggers';
```

The values should be 1 or "ON". If not you can activate them and try again

```
EXEC sp_configure 'nested triggers', 1;
EXEC sp_dboption 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME', 'recursive triggers', true;
```